# Resize User Photo

Tags: image, image-transforms, user-profile

I know about `getPhotoUrl(size`) but this always gives me a square. Is there any way of scaling/cropping the user photo? Let's say I want the photo 100x50, would that be possible? By looking at the code I think it's not, so the only option I can think of is every time the `onBeforeSaveUser` is triggered, I mirror the user photo to an asset field. Any better ideas?

Comment: Brandon or Brad mentioned plan for Craft 3 was to make it a 'proper' asset...so you'll certainly be able to then...

Comment: great news to here, but I'm more looking more for a solution right now :)  Worst case I'll go with the event solution, I just wanted to see if anyone has come up with a better solution yet...